# Calculating mean, min, max, sum of a list of integers - what's the complexity?

Tags: javascript, haskell, time-complexity, computer-science, complexity-theory

This is sort of a silly question that's been bugging me.

I have a list of 100k numbers that I am calculating some statistics for. Specifically, I am computing the mean, minimum, maximum, and sum of these numbers. I'm doing it using a fold. In JavaScript:

```
// define folding functions:
let mean = (a, b, index, array) => a + b / array.length
let max = (a, b) => Math.max(a, b)
let min = (a, b) => Math.min(a, b)
let sum = (a, b) => a + b

let fold = initial => f => data =>
  Math.round(data.reduce(f, initial))

// functions we can consume:
let averageDistance = fold(0)(mean)
let maxDistance = fold(-Infinity)(max)
let minDistance = fold(Infinity)(min)
let totalDistance = fold(0)(sum)

// compute stats:
let data = [1, 2, 3, ...]
let a = averageDistance(data)
let b = maxDistance(data)
let c = minDistance(data)
let d = totalDistance(data)
```

The time complexity of this is clearly *O(n)* for each statistic `averageDistance`, `maxDistance`, etc. Computed over all 4 statistics, the complexity is *O(4n)*.

Now, I can instead compute all 4 statistics in a single loop, using either a [transducer](https://clojure.org/reference/transducers) (a similar optimization to Haskell's fusion), or by inlining eveything into a `for` loop:

```
let a = 0
let b = -Infinity
let c = Infinity
let d = 0

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  a = mean(a, averageDistance(data[i]), i, data)
  b = max(b, maxDistance(data[i]))
  c = min(c, minDistance(data[i]))
  d = sum(d, totalDistance(data[i]))
}
```

This solution only does a single loop, so intuitively it does it in *O(n)* time (an improvement over *4n* from before).

But it still does the same amount of work as before: (100k integers)*(4 statistics) = 400k computations.

Is one solution really faster than another? Is the difference in space complexity (not in time)? If no to both of these, why bother with transducers or fusion at all?

Comment: why do you think putting the four operations in a loop makes it O(n)? It doesn't, since the loop is doing four operations each of which takes O(n) time.

Comment: for large data structures you gain from cache affinity; think of paging a section of the data to fast memory location (CPU cache) so the consecutive look ups much faster.  The visible part:  elimination of loop counters is negligible.

Comment: @AdamSmith Wouldn't traditional analysis call this O(n)?

Comment: @karakfa So the one loop instead of 4 loops is faster because the item is loaded into L1/L2 cache once and not 4 times, cutting down on memory IO?

Comment: In Big-O complexity analysis, there isn't really a meaningful distinction between _O(n)_ and _O(c*n)_. Since `f(x) ~ O(g(n)` iff `forall x > y . |f(x)| < M|g(x)|` for some `M` and `y`

Comment: @bchemy correct, that's where most of the speed up comes from.

Comment: In the fused version, it is often possible to avoid realizing the entire list. The list may be consumed as it is produced, dramatically reducing GC costs by keeping all the churn in the nursery. In many cases, the compiler can eliminate the list altogether, avoiding any GC cost and keeping much more of the computation in machine registers.

Comment: @dfeuer Could you explain in more detail, or link to an article? You mean memory consumed by intermediate results can be reused/GC'd more effectively when using fusion than without? Does the compiler have to support fusion (eg. GHC) or can this be an application-level optimization (eg. transducers, or Lodash loop fusion)?

Comment: Something that is O(4n) is also O(n).

Comment: [Here's a reference for that fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Multiplication_by_a_constant). The rest of the article should go into more detail about why that's the case.

Comment: Are you asking about this javascript code (which works with arrays, not linked lists and is strict) or about hypothetical Haskell code which does something comparable with lists and lazily? These are two entirely different situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function:

```
Stats_A(array[1...n])
    sum = 0
    for i = 1 to n do
        sum = sum + array[i]

    avg = 0
    for i = 1 to n do
        avg = avg + array[i]
    avg = avg / n

    min = array[1]
    for i = 1 to n do
        if array[i] < min then
            min = array[i]

    max = array[1]
    for i = 1 to n do
        if array[i] > max then
            max = array[i]

    return (sum, avg, min, max)
```

And this function:

```
Stats_B(array[1...n])
    sum = 0
    min = max = array[1]
    for i = 1 to n do
        sum = sum + array[i]
        if array[i] < min then
            min = array[i]
        else if array[i] > max then
            max = array[i]

    return (sum, sum / n, min, max)
```

Both have the same linear time complexity `O(n)`. We can assign costs to basic operations and work out more details expressions for the time complexities of these functions, and then we will find that `Stats_A` does more work than `Stats_B`, but not asymptotically more work. We can let:

1. memory accesses (read/write) take time `a`
2. +, -, *, / take time `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, respectively
3. comparisons (<, >, =) take time `f`

Now we can compute the more detailed runtime expressions:

This function:

```
Stats_A(array[1...n])
    sum = 0                      // a
    for i = 1 to n do            // a + n * (f + b + a)
        sum = sum + array[i]     // n * (2 * b + 3 * a)
                                 // =   (2 + 4 * n) * a
                                 //   + (    3 * n) * b
                                 //   + (    1 * n) * f

    avg = 0                      // a
    for i = 1 to n do            // a + n * (f + b + a)
        avg = avg + array[i]     // n * (2 * b + 3 * a)
    avg = avg / n                // 3 * a + e
                                 // =   (5 + 4 * n) * a
                                 //   + (    3 * n) * b
                                 //   + (    1 * n) * f
                                 //   + (1        ) * e

    min = array[1]               // 2 * a + b
    for i = 1 to n do            // a + n * (f + b + a)
        if array[i] < min then   // n * (2 * a + b + f)
            min = array[i]       // n * (2 * a + b)
                                 // =   (3 + 5 * n) * a
                                 //   + (1 + 3 * n) * b
                                 //   + (    2 * n) * f

    max = array[1]               // 2 * a + b
    for i = 1 to n do            // a + n * (f + b + a)
        if array[i] > max then   // n * (2 * a + b + f)
            max = array[i]       // n * (2 * a + b)
                                 // =   (3 + 5 * n) * a
                                      + (1 + 3 * n) * b
                                      + (    2 * n) * f

    return (sum, avg, min, max)  // =   (5        ) * a

    // total:   (13 + 18 * n) * a
    //        + ( 2 + 12 * n) * b
    //        + ( 1         ) * e
    //        + (      6 * n) * f
    //        = n * (18a + 12b + 6f) + (13a + 2b + e)
```

And this function:

```
Stats_B(array[1...n])
    sum = 0                           // a
    min = max = array[1]              // 3a + b
    for i = 1 to n do                 // a + n * (f + b + a)
        sum = sum + array[i]          // n * (3 * a + 2 * b)
        if array[i] < min then        // n * (b + 2 * a + f)
            min = array[i]            // n * (b + 2 * a)
        else if array[i] > max then   // n * (b + 2 * a + f)
            max = array[i]            // n * (b + 2 * a)

    return (sum, sum / n, min, max)   // 5a + e

    // total:   ( 9 + 12 * n) * a
              + ( 1 +  7 * n) * b
              + ( 1         ) * e
              + (      3 * n) * f
              = n * (12a + 7b + 3f) + (9a + b + e)
```

The first function takes strictly longer than the second function; in the limit, the ratio of their runtimes approaches the quotient of their slopes:

```
(18a + 12b + 6f) / (12a + 7b + 3f)
```

We can observe that the denominator is strictly less than 2/3 of the numerator; therefore, the ratio is strictly greater than 3/2. We would expect, for any given input, `Stats_A` to take an amount approaching 50% longer than `Stats_B` as the input size increases without bound.

Comment: Wow, this is a really intuitive way to look at it! Is there a name for this kind of analysis? It looks something like Halstead complexity.